# What is the most efficient (pythonic) way to ignore words in a list that has parantheses?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, list

I have the following list

```
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']
```

Using re I was able to ignore the words in the parentheses. Like below

```
import re 
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']
for i in x:
    ko= list(re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", i))
    print (ko)
```

but I get the output in the below format

```
['A', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'u', 'i', 'l', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'm', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'l', ' ']
['t', 'r', 'i', '-', 'c', 'o', 'm', ' ', 'm', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'l', ' ']
```

What I ideally want is like below in the fewest possible lines of code. (I know my code is currently inefficient)

Ideal output required

```
['Accara building model', 'tri-com model']
```

Comment: you get chars because you use `list()`. You should create empty list before loo and `append` results to this list.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `list()` but you should create empty list before loop and append results to this list

```
import re

x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']
results = []

for i in x:
    ko = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", i)
    resutls.append(ko.strip())

print(results)
```

Result

```
['Accara building model', 'tri-com model']
```

You can even use list comprehension

```
import re

x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']

results = [re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", i).strip() for i in x]

print(results)
```

---

**BTW:** I use `strip()` to remove space at the end. But you could remove this space with regex which starts with space `" [\(\[].*?[\)\]]"`.

---

**EDIT:** as Mark Meyer suggested in comment you can also compile regex - so it will not have to do it in every loop.

```
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']

pattern = re.compile(" [\(\[].*?[\)\]]")
results = [re.sub(pattern, "", i) for i in x]

print(results)
```

---

**BTW:** if you are sure that elments will have always the same structure then you can remove it without regex but using `split(' (')`

```
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)', 'name without parentheses']

results = [i.split(' (',1)[0] for i in x]

print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess your last solution is the most efficient for my case as it involves less number of codes relatively. No extra creation of empty list and appending.

Comment: If efficiency is an issue, maybe compiling the re outside the loop would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, try this :

```
import re
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']
output = []
for i in x:
    ko= re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", i)
    output.append(ko)
```

**Output** : `output` list looks like

```
["Accara building model", "tri-com model"]
```

When you are using `list(re.sub(...))` you are basically making the output string (after replacing) into a list format.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']

print([ "".join(list(re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", i))) for i in x ])


python test
['Accara building model ', 'tri-com model ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct, you need not cast it to list

```
import re 
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', i))

print (y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Being Pythonic doesn't need to be fewest possible lines of code. *Explaining Explicit is Better than Implicit from the Zen of Python*

```
x = ['Accara building model (ABM)','tri-com model (tcm)']
result=[]
for i in x:
    result.append(r.sub(r'\(.*\)','',i))
```